# Assigning multiple values to a single dictionary key python

Tags: python, fix-protocol

i'm trying to assignee repeating FIX tag values to a single dictionary key.

the line i'm reading contains multiple <269> FIX tags whit different values:

```
<class 'list'>: ['8=FIX.X.X', '9=XXX', '35=V', '34=XXXXXX', '49=XXX.XXXXX.X', '56=XXX.XXXXX', '52=XXXXXXXX-XX:XX:XX.XXX', '128=XXXX,XXXX', '262=XXX/XXX-XXXXXXXXXX', '263=X', '265=X', '1021=X', '264=X', '267=X', '269=0', '269=1', '146=X', '55=XXX/XXX', '167=XXXXX', '1300=X', '63=X', '10=XXX']
```

each time i run my code 269: 0 is overwritten by 269: 1 i'm looking for a way to append both values to the same key "269: 0,1" (unfortunately wasn't able to find a method i understand on similar question threads).

here is my code:

```
import os
import time
import csv

csvPath = 'C:/""/""/""/""/FixTakerLogs/'
logsPath = 'C:/""/""/""/""/FixTakerLogs/'

print('[START]:', 'MsgMarketDataRequest.csv')
fileMarketDataRequest = open('C:/Users/apanasenko/Desktop/LOGS/FixTakerLogs/MsgMarketDataRequest.log','r')
with open(csvPath + 'MsgMarketDataRequest.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvLogon:
    msgDict = {'8': '','9': '','35': '','49': '','56': '','34': '','52': '','128': '','262': '','263': '','264': '',
                 '265': '','267': '','269': '','146': '','55': '','167': '','63': '','12008': '','64': '','193': '',
                 '271': '','1201': '','1202': '','1300': '','10': ''}
    csvWriter = csv.DictWriter(csvLogon, msgDict.keys())
    csvWriter.writeheader()
    for line in fileMarketDataRequest:
        line = line.rstrip()
        line = line.split(';')
        X = len(line) - 1
        line = line[0:X]
        for tag in line:
            tag = tag.split('=')
            msgDict[tag[0]] = tag[1]
        csvWriter.writerow(msgDict)
        msgDict = {}
csvLogon.close()
print('[END]:', 'MsgMarketDataRequest.csv')
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are perhaps familiar with the list? It's Python's mutable multi-value store, which you can iterate over all the values in and so on. For example, one possible replacement for your code that reads

```
msgDict = {'8': '','9': '','35': '','49': '','56': '','34': '','52': '','128': '','262': '','263': '','264': '',
             '265': '','267': '','269': '','146': '','55': '','167': '','63': '','12008': '','64': '','193': '',
             '271': '','1201': '','1202': '','1300': '','10': ''}
```

would use a dictionary comprehension driven by a list of key values to make the dictionary initialisation more compact (and, hopefully, more readable):

```
msg_dict = {key: '' for key in ['8', '9', '35', ... , '1'0']}
```

You'll see I prefer the naming style suggested in PEP 8, but style isn't as important as writing working code to start with - there's plenty of time to learn to polish later. It's just become a habit so I thought I'd mention it.

Along similar lines (it's always best to write readable code when you can so this is just a hint - it works the same as your code) you might replace

```
X = len(line) - 1
line = line[0:X]
```

with

```
line = line[:-1]
```

There's no need to use the `len` function when negative indexing will do, but if you haven't come across it, it's worth knowing about.

The key portion of your code is the one that reads

```
for tag in line:
    if tag not in line:
        tag = tag.split('=')
        msgDict[tag[0]] = tag[1]
```

That last assignment is guaranteed to overwrite any existing key. But you could use a list for the values by instead initialising the values of `msg_dict` to an empty list like so:

```
msg_dict = {key: [] for key in ['8', '9', '35', ... , '1'0']}
```

and appending the tags as you find them:

```
for tag in line:
    name, val = tag.split('=')
    if name in msgDict:
        msgDict[name].append(val)
```

You'll see I used an "unpacking assignment" so I could use names rather than indexing - again, such techniques help readability. When you have iterated over all the tags, each key in `msgDict` will be a list of all the values encountered.

Of course you will then have the problem of how to sensibly write that to a CSV file so you can read it back (hint: you don't have to use CSV files for everything!). But I hope that's progress of a sort. Good luck!

Comment: thank you a lot for the detailed answer and for taking the time to explain, i'm happy to report it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting lists into the dictionary like this:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> msg = defaultdict(list)
>>> for key, value in [(1, 2), (3, 4), (1, 3), (3, 5)] :
...     msg[key].append(value)
... 
>>> dict(msg)
{1: [2, 3], 3: [4, 5]}
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

below you can find the code that worked for me:

```
import os
import time
import csv

csvPath = 'C:/'
logsPath = 'C:/'

print('[START]:', 'MsgMarketDataRequest.csv')
fileMarketDataRequest = open('C:/','r')
with open(csvPath + 'MsgMarketDataRequest.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvMarketDataRequest:
    msgDict = {key: [] for key in ['8', '9', '35', '49','56','34','52','128','262','263','264','265','267','269','146','55','167','63','12008','64','193','271','1201','1202','1300','10']}
    csvWriter = csv.DictWriter(csvMarketDataRequest, msgDict.keys())
    csvWriter.writeheader()
    for line in fileMarketDataRequest:
        line = line.rstrip()
        line = line.split(';')
        X = len(line) - 1
        line = line[0:X]
        for tag in line:
            name, val = tag.split('=')
            if name in msgDict:
                msgDict[name].append(val)
        csvWriter.writerow(msgDict)
        msgDict = {key: [] for key in ['8', '9', '35', '49','56','34','52','128','262','263','264','265','267','269','146','55','167','63','12008','64','193','271','1201','1202','1300','10']}
csvMarketDataRequest.close()
print('[END]:', 'MsgMarketDataRequest.csv')
```

Thank you for your help.